# How can I mail all exceptions?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to mail all error or exceptions in CakePHP 3.
Which one of solutions are correct?

1. Write new log engine
2. Write new error handler

Comment: Write an error handler.

Comment: @burzum Can I register more than one ErrorHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote custom error handler and register it.

```
// In config/bootstrap.php
namespace App\Error;

use Cake\Error\ErrorHandler;
use Cake\Mailer\Email;

/**
 * AppError
 *
 * @package App\Error
 */
class AppError extends ErrorHandler
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _displayException($exception)
    {
        parent::_displayException($exception);

        try {
            $email = new Email('default');
            $email->to('bug@example.com')
                ->emailFormat(Email::MESSAGE_HTML)
                ->subject('Bug !!!')
                ->template('bug')
                ->set(['exception' => $exception])
                ->send();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Disable trace for internal errors.
            $this->_options['trace'] = false;
            $message = sprintf(
                "[%s] %s\n%s", // Keeping same message format
                get_class($e),
                $e->getMessage(),
                $e->getTraceAsString()
            );
            trigger_error($message, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

And create "bug" template:

```
// In src/Template/Email/html/bug.ctp
<h1><?= $exception->getMessage() ?></h1>

<p>
    <?= nl2br($exception->getTraceAsString()) ?>
</p>
```